# Como armazenar ids diferentes para EditTexts com o mesmo nome?

Tags: android

Eu tenho uma interação e dentro dele crio vários `EditText` dinamicamente, mas como manter o id para cada `EditText`?

**Meu código**:

```
for (int j = 0; j < vet.length; j++) {
    EditText nome = new EditText(this);
    nome.setId(0+x);
    EditText sobrenome = new EditText(this);
    sobrenome.setId(1+x);

    x = x+2;
}
```

Eu tentei esta lógica, mas percebi que seu o tamanho do meu vetor for 3 por exemplo, cria 3 pares de `EditText` (nome + sobrenome), porém os 3 pares ficam com o mesmo id, que faz sentido, e eu precisava pelo menos saber se cliquei no 1º nome, no 2º ou no 3º.

Nem com o `onClick()` eu consigo diferenciar os "nomes".
Obs: Estou colocando tudo estes EditTexts em um `LinearLayout`, se fosse em um `ListView` eu poderia pegar o position pelo menos.

Você conhecem algum método do Android para conseguir isso? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Não entendo quando diz que os 3 pares ficam com o mesmo id.

Comment: me expressei mal, na verdade fica assim: nome:4 sobrenome:5; nome:4 sobrenome:5; nome:4 sobrenome:5;

Comment: Por aquilo que vejo no código deveriam ser todos diferentes. A única coisa que falta é inicializar a variável x: `int x = 1;`

Comment: Eu inicializo fora do for, mas acho que fica com o mesmo id porque os EditText tem o mesmo nome, então mesmo os que já foram criados recebem o valor do último id.

Comment: Eu precisava mesmo diferenciar de alguma forma os nomes. No ListView um simples getItem(Position) funcionaria.

Comment: Onde é que eles são adicionados ao LinearLayout?

Comment: Estou jogando dentro de um único LinearLayout que fica dentro de um scrollView, estrutura bem simples.

Answer (score 3):

O que está faltando é os *EditText's*, depois de criados, serem adicionados ao *LinearLayout*:

```
int x = 1;
for (int j = 0; j < vet.length; j++) {
    EditText nome = new EditText(this);
    nome.setId(x);
    adicionarAoLayout(nome);
    x++;
    EditText sobrenome = new EditText(this);
    sobrenome.setId(x);
    x++;
    adicionarAoLayout(sobrenome);
}
```

Onde `adicionarAoLayout()` é o método que adiciona os *EditText's* ao seu *LinearLayout*.

Answer (score 0):

tenta :

```
for (int j = 0, int x = 1; j < vet.length; j++, x += 2)
{
    EditText nome = new EditText(this);
    nome.setId(x);
    EditText sobrenome = new EditText(this);
    sobrenome.setId(x+1);
}
```